# How to add 'id' to the tbody tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add 'id' to the tbody tag dynamically.
How to add 'id' to the tbody tag dynamically ?
Here is the code:

```
function tableCreate() {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var tbl = document.createElement('table');
    tbl.style.width = '100%';
    tbl.setAttribute('border', '1');
    var tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            if (i == 2 && j == 1) {
                break
            } else {
                var td = document.createElement('td');
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\u0020'))
                i == 1 && j == 1 ? td.setAttribute('rowSpan', '2') : null;
                tr.appendChild(td)
            }
        }
        tbdy.appendChild(tr);
    }
    tbl.appendChild(tbdy);
    body.appendChild(tbl)
}
```

Comment: I am able to add id to the table. Inside the table tag, I have <tbody> tag. To this <tbody>, I want to add id using javascript. Something like this :

<tbody id='testBody'> 
<tbody>

I have already used:
tbdy.id = 'testBody';
But its not working.

Comment: How it is not working, seems fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code in jsbin and added `tbdy.id = 'testBody';` right after the `createElement` for `tbody`. Seems to work for me.

https://jsbin.com/dibupewifa/edit?js,output

Image - [Table HTML for the Chrome dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f571r.png)

Answer (score 1):

Add following code after getting tbody tag

tbdy.setAttribute("id", "myid");

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the DOM properties.
There is an property .`id` which you need to set on your element.

Here is more about that:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_id.asp

So as you said if you want to set an `Id` to your tbody dynamically, what you need to do is after you create your body like you did allready:

```
   var tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');
```

you need to set an `id` for your body, like this:

```
tbody.id = "something";
```

or

```
 tbody.setAttribute("id", "someDynamicId");
```

This will work because Id is part of [DOM element properties](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp) which you should read about.

Comment: OP already has a reference to tbody when they create it ... why search for it in the dom?

Comment: @charlietfl that's true it could be written document.body right ?

Comment: I am trying to set an Id for <tbody> and not <body>.

Comment: I am able to set id to the <body> and <table>. Inside the table tag, I have <tbody> tag. To this <tbody>, I want to set id using javascript. Something like this : <tbody id='testBody'> <tbody> I have already used: tbdy.id = 'testBody'; But its not working.